# $GL(V)$ representations and Schur modules.

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $W$ be a fine dimensional complex vector space of dimension $n$ and $L_{\lambda}W$ the Schur module associate to the partition $\lambda=(\lambda_1, \cdots,\lambda_{n-1})$, where $\sum_i \lambda_i=n$. I have to prove the following theorem: Every irreducible representation of $GL(W)$ is isomorphic to 
$$ L_{\lambda}(W) \otimes (\Lambda^nW)^{\otimes d} $$
for some partition $\lambda$ and $d \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
Can you give me a reference o say the main steps of the proof? Thank you.

Comment: This result is proved in many books on representation theory, e.g., see the book of J.A. Green: *Polynomial Representations of $GL_n$.*